# parsing inputs in jpanel, compiles fine but doesnt run. PLEASE EXPLAIN

Tags: java, jlabel

Code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class check2
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

String array1[], 
        array2[],
        array3[], 
        array4[];
Double hours[],
        pay[],
        total[],
        sum[], 
        over[],
        social[];

array1= new String [5];
array2= new String [5];
array3= new String [5];
array4= new String [5];

social = new Double [5];
hours= new Double [5];
pay= new Double [5];
total= new Double [5];
sum= new Double [5];
over= new Double [5];


  JTextField name = new JTextField(5);
  JTextField ss = new JTextField(5);
   JTextField hw = new JTextField(5);
JTextField wage = new JTextField(5);

  JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));

for (int i = 0;i<5 ;i++ )
{

  myPanel.add(new JLabel("Name: "));
  myPanel.add(name);
  myPanel.add(new JLabel("Social Security:"));
  myPanel.add(ss);
  myPanel.add(new JLabel("Hours Worked:"));
  myPanel.add(hw);
  myPanel.add(new JLabel("Wage:"));
  myPanel.add(wage);

array1[i]=name.getText();
array2[i]=ss.getText();
social[i]=Double.parseDouble(array2[i]);
array3[i]=hw.getText();
hours[i]=Double.parseDouble(array3[i]);
array4[i]=wage.getText();
pay[i]=Double.parseDouble(array4[i]);

}

for (int u=0;u<5 ;u++ )
{
  if (pay[u] < 40)
    {
    total[u] = pay[u] * hours[u];
System.out.println (array1[u] + " gross pay is " + total[u]);   
    }
else if (hours[u] > 40)
        {
hours[u] = hours[u] - 40;
sum[u]= 40 * pay[u];
over[u]= hours[u] * pay[u] * 1.5;
total[u] = sum[u] + over[u];
        }
}



  int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
           "Please Enter details", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
     System.out.println("name: " + name.getText());
     System.out.println("Social security: " + ss.getText());
      System.out.println("hours worked: " + hw.getText());
       System.out.println("Total pay: " + wage.getText());

       for (int a=0;a<5 ;a++ )
       {
           JFrame window = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
           JLabel first = new JLabel ("name:" +array1[a]);
           first.setBounds(250,20,100,10);
           JLabel Totalpay = new JLabel("pay: " +total[a]);
            Totalpay.setBounds(250, 20, 100, 10);
           JLabel bank = new JLabel ("" +social[a]);
           bank.setBounds (0,90,100,10);
           window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             window.setSize(400, 150);
            window.setVisible(true);
             window.setLayout(null);
            window.setResizable(false);
         window.add(first);
        window.add(bank);
       }
    }
 }
}
```

compiles fine.
Output:

```
 ---------- runn ----------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at check2.main(check2.java:60)
```

i am a beginner at java and just learned about jpanel. i have a few questions on what is happening, sorry if they are obvious. i have been doing alot of reasearch on that error. i found that its from trying to parse a string like "adam" into a double. when a user inputs values into jpanel with does that automatically assume it is a string? if so, shouldnt the lines after parse it?
for example:

```
 myPanel.add(new JLabel("Wage:"));
 myPanel.add(wage);
 array4[i]=wage.getText();
 pay[i]=Double.parseDouble(array4[i]);
```

`
sorry it might be hard to tell out of context because the arrays. thats why i included all my code. i had this program working before the loops and arrays. I just dont see the contradiction. it would be appreciated if someone could explain what im doing wrong.

Comment: what is the content of `array2[i]`, `array3[i]` and `array4[i]`?

Comment: @piyushj array2 is the social security input from the user and parsed into a double and stored in social[]. array3[] is suppose to be their hours and parsed into a double value of hours[]. array4[] is the wage parsed into a double in pay[].

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues I can see your code. But I will give an insight on why you are getting the exception 'NumberFormatException'.

In your code `myPanel.add(ss);`(line 52) will add JTextField to your JPanel.
`array2[i]=ss.getText();` (line 59) will assign  the value from this text field to array2[i]. 
However, this textfield doesn't have a value yet. So an empty String is assigned to array2[i]. Now in line 60, `social[i]=Double.parseDouble(array2[i]);` you are attempting to parse this empty string into double value which is not permitted and throws the exception java.lang.NumberFormatException.